# $_POST array empty

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have this code:

```
<div id="messageDiv">
<form>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20" id="message"></textarea></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="return sendmail()">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name='reset'>
</form>
</div>
```

then i have my JS:

```
function sendmail()
{
  var mail = document.getElementById('message').value;
  window.location.href = "http://www.rainbowcode.net/apps_dev.php/profiles/mail?id="+mailid;
  return false;
}
```

when i `alert(mail)` i get the correct value but when i get to my new page via window.location.href i want to access that value...my form is a "post" when i do a `print_r($_POST['message'])` i get an empty array..please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your html that might affect it

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20" id="message"></textarea></textarea>
```

should be

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
```

And also that is not how a post form is done. the send mail function  is not helping at all

```
<form method='post' action='http://www.rainbowcode.net/apps_dev.php/profiles/mail'>
   <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
   <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" name='reset'>
</form>
```

This should work

UPDATE:

You can always add hidden values that can be used for different purposes without being visible in the form. Like your mail id, it  can be added to the form too:

```
<input name='mailid' type='hidden' value='somevalue' />
```

Comment: to send data through post you need to specify it as a from attribute, method and action @Helloise

Comment: thank you but i also need to send my mailid...how will i incorporate that in the action='http://www.rainbowcode.net/apps_dev.php/profiles/mail?mailid=....' ???
thanks

Answer (score 7):

By using `window.location.href` you just change the link you are going to (by that refreshing the page to the desired page, which in your case is a page that gets an id from the URL).
If you want to post values, use `document.MyForm.submit();`

EDIT:
Obviously you will have to add a normal `<form>` tag, and not just an empty one.
Add a name/id to it so you could refer to it using JS + method post + action as an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` isn't set to `post`:

Update your HTML code to:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post">
```

---

**Update**

```
function sendmail()
{
  var mail = document.getElementById('message').value;
  window.location.href = "http://www.rainbowcode.net/apps_dev.php/profiles/mail?id="+mailid;
  return false;
}
```

Where is `mailid` defined? Also, are you trying to `print_r($_POST['message'])` in the page you're redirecting to from JavaScript? Try `print_r($_GET['id'])` instead.

Comment: i added this but it made no diff though.. where SCRIPT_NAME would be my script name??

Comment: @Helloise Smit: Yes, `SCRIPT_NAME` will be the name of your script, but looking at your JavaScript I get the impression that you're trying to post the form to another page by doing a a `GET` request. It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do...

Comment: ok i have it as my script name..mailid is a global var that i set in another js funtion and it contains the right id when i rediret to a new page i just want to access the message the user typed into <textarea>

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of obvious. Popup window you open does not contain same request variables as "parent" page which opens it. It's a new HTTP request.

Transfer data between "parent" window and pop-up through session (`$_SESSION`, http://hr.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php ).